# Could not parse the remainder in django {% for clause

Tags: django

Inside an HTML I am trying to perform a double for, which the second one inherits data from the father, as follow:

```
{% for category in categories %}
            <li><a href="/categories/{{ category.id }}/">{{ category.name }}</a>
            {% for cat in category.objects.filter(parent=category.id) %}
                {% if forloop.first %} 
                <ul class="noJS">
                {% endif %}
                    <li><a href="/categories/{{ cat.id }}">{{cat.name}}</a></li> 
                </ul>
            {% endfor %}

            {% endfor %}
```

The problem is that I am getting error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /
Could not parse the remainder: '(parent=category.id))' from 'ca

tegory.objects.filter(parent=category.id))'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.4.3
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Could not parse the remainder: '(parent=category.id))' from 'category.objects.filter(parent=category.id))'
```

Any idea?

Comment: it's wrong! You are looping the same model?

Comment: My model inherits from itself, like a tree

Comment: maybe you should try another way than filtering it inside the template

Comment: share your relevant models and views. YOu might have to use managers to accomplish this. <object>.objects dont work. May be there is a simpler way of doing it..

Comment: You have an extra parenthesis (maybe it's a typo) `category.objects.filter(parent=category.id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using MPTT so I just call a method for children nodes:

```
        {% for cat in category.get_children %}
```

that is available from MPTT

Answer (score 1):

Idea:

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    .........

    def data(self):
        return Category.objects.filter(id=self.id)
```

template

```
{% for category in categories %}
<li><a href="/categories/{{ category.id }}/">{{ category.name }}</a>
    {% for cat in category.data %}
        {% if forloop.first %} 
        <ul class="noJS">
        {% endif %}
            <li><a href="/categories/{{ cat.id }}">{{cat.name}}</a></li> 
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a relationship, even a self-referential one, you get an accessor for the reverse relation. If you haven't set `related_name`, that will just be `category_set`. So you can just do:

```
{% for cat in category.category_set.all %}
```